SQL Exists Clause Join Key Selection
I have this table
Table: Insurance
pid is the primary key (column with unique values) for this table.
Each row of this table contains information about one policy where:
pid is the policyholder's policy ID.
tiv_2015 is the total investment value in 2015 and tiv_2016 is the total investment value in 2016.
lat is the latitude of the policy holder's city. It's guaranteed that lat is not NULL.
lon is the longitude of the policy holder's city. It's guaranteed that lon is not NULL.
I want to find pids that not located in the same city as any other policyholder (i.e., the (lat, lon) attribute pairs must be unique).
I tried to use exist clause for this probelm because I WANT TO LEARN how to use it
Here is the sample table



pid
tiv_2015
tiv_2016
lat
lon




1
10
5
10
10


2
20
20
20
20


3
10
30
20
20


4
10
40
40
40



If I run this query
select pid, lat, lon
from insurance a
where exists 
(select lat, lon      
 from insurance b 
 where a.lat = b.lat 
 and a.lon = b.lon
 group by 1, 2 
 having count(*)= 1  
)

it return the correct answer



pid
lat
lon




1
10
10


4
40
40



But if I run
select pid, lat, lon
from insurance a
where exists 
(select lat, lon 
 from insurance b 
 where a.l=pid = b.pid
 group by 1, 2 
 having count(*)= 1 
)

it returns



pid
lat
lon




1
10
10


2
20
20


3
20
20


4
40
40



which is not correct
I have a no idea why join with the unique id will give me incorrect answer. How should I choose the right join key for Exist?
I can not find anything that explains how the join works for Exist in documents

With:
select pid, lat, lon
from insurance a
where exists 
(select lat, lon      
 from insurance b 
 where a.lat = b.lat 
 and a.lon = b.lon
 group by 1, 2 
 having count(*)= 1  
)

You are saying that, for each row, check all those those rows that have the same lat and lon and when grouped by lat, lon its count is 1. So that eliminates the rows with same lat, lon having count more than 1.
However in second SQL, you are doing the match by pid. For each row, there is only one match using pid (itself), so EXISTS is true for all the rows and you get back all the rows.

It looks like missunderstanding of the EXISTS operator and its role. Two main things to know are:

The EXISTS operator is used to test for the existence of any record in a subquery.

The EXISTS operator returns TRUE if the subquery returns one or more records.


So, the EXISTS operator returns TRUE or FALSE depending on the subquery returning any number of rows or no rows at all, respectively. It is absolutely irrelevant what columns are in the selection list of the subquery.
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
WITH
  insurance ( pid, tiv_2015, tiv_2016, lat, lon ) AS
    ( Select 1, 10,  5, 10, 10 Union All
      Select 2, 20, 20, 20, 20 Union All
      Select 3, 10, 30, 20, 20 Union All
      Select 4, 10, 40, 40, 40
    )

The EXISTS subquery, when correlated over pid, does the aggregation for every pid meaning you are aggregating row by row (not an aggregation) resulting with all rows HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
Select pid, lat, lon
From insurance a
Where exists ( Select lat, lon      
         -- OR Select 1         instead of the above result is the same (Try It) 
               From insurance b 
               Where a.pid = b.pid
               Group By lat, lon    -- don't use ordinals here - use columns for readability, maintainability and avoinding errors if selection list changes
               Having Count(*) = 1 
             )

/*      R e s u l t : 
pid lat lon
--- --- ---
  1  10  10
  2  20  20
  3  20  20
  4  40  40      */

You can test it with
... 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

which will return no rows at all since they are all HAVING COUNT(*) = 1.
However, when the correlation is established over lat and lon there will be two rows correlated having lat, lon 20 and Count(*) for those two rows will be 2 resulting with Having clause excluding them from the resultset.
Select pid, lat, lon
From insurance a
Where exists ( Select lat, lon      
         -- OR Select 1         instead of the above result is the same (Try It) 
               From insurance b 
               Where a.lat = b.lat And a.lon = b.lon
               Group By lat, lon    -- don't use ordinals here - use columns for readability, maintainability and avoinding errors if selection list changes
               Having Count(*) = 1 
             )

/*    R e s u l t :      ( for HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )
pid lat lon
--- --- ---
  1  10  10
  4  40  40    */

Again, you can do the same test as above putting HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 which will fetch you the two remaining rows.
/*    R e s u l t :      ( for HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
pid lat lon
--- --- ---
  2  20  20
  3  20  20      */

